# Why the lambda function returns a procedure?

Tags: lambda, racket

```
(lambda () (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y))) (3 4))
#<procedure>
```

Why the function returns a procedure but not directly 5 instead?

Comment: You have paren errors in your code. You probably meant to write `((lambda (x y) (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y))))  3  4)`.

Comment: By the way, the pattern of `((lambda ....) ....)` has two open-parens. It's the result of filling in function application: `(function argument ...)`, where you plug in `(lambda (parameter ...) body)` for the function. One open-paren for function application, and one open-paren for the lambda. Some people pronounce it "left left lambda", and its a sign that you're creating a function and immediately applying it.

Comment: Yea, I found it and tried to close this question. Thanks.